# Setting selection in a rad combo box

Tags: visual-studio

I'm sure this is quite simple but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm just trying to set the selection of a RadComboBox using its onDataBound function.

```
protected void ReTo_DataBound(object sender, RadComboBoxItemEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("e");
                var combo = sender as RadComboBox;
                if (combo.FindItemByText("Jack Johnson") != null)
                    combo.FindItemByText("Jack Johnson").Selected = true;
            }
```

I think i'm calling the combobox incorrectly.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't solve it from here but your FindItemByText is "smelly" :), don't look for a item by his string value, it could be one char difference...

Try to check item by value not text and see what happens.

cheers

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that. No matter what find I use it doesn't find it though i know it's in there.Fairly sure the problem is with how I'm trying to grab the combobox.

Comment: and also, why do you setting combobox selection ondatabound..maybe if you try the same thing in the page_load?